# Unable to resolve service context while attempting to activate controller when scaffolding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I was doing a simple `HTTP GET` operation, I will display person data as `JSON` after hitting my url

at first, all worked

**Working code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Apitest4.Models;

namespace Apitest4.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PeopleController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
        {
            using (var context = new ModelContext())
            {
                return context.People.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code you are seeing is a slightly modified version of `WeatherController` (Visual Studio 2019), which I was using to make my own `PeopleController`. This code gives me proper API response I expected

Then I wanted to do the same using an automated approach, since I have to cover a lot of tables

[Vs Code: 2019]

[Controllers(Right Click)>Add>New Sacffolded Item>Api Controller with Actions using Entity Framework]

**Auto-generated Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Apitest4.Models;

namespace Apitest4.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PeopleController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly ModelContext _context;

        public PeopleController(ModelContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/People
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Person>>> GetPeople()
        {
            return await _context.People.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

This code is givine me this error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Apitest4.Models.ModelContext' while attempting to activate 'Apitest4.Controllers.PeopleController'.
```

Full error message:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mol7i.png)

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Apitest4
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Though I am new to .net, I just don't get it, Why it is not getting context properly? I didn't change any import. Please point my mistakes.

TIA

Comment: Hi @Frost, this error message means you do not register the service. Please share your Startup.cs.

Comment: @Rena added startup.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure register your DbContext in Startup.cs like below:

```
services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Refrence:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core

**Update:**

store the connection string in appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

Comment: Ok. You actually as what my answer said. You do not register the service in your startup. Just add the code above in your startup.cs. Be sure the connection string of the database is correct. More details you could refer to the document I shared above.

Comment: thanks alot, it woked, but can you show me how to put my connection string in configuration [ right now it is hardcoded]

Comment: You can put the string as it is in the OnConfiguring method in your context.

`builder.Services.AddDbContext<CAPTATECContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("YOURCONNECTION"));`